# Letters in String to Dictionary Values

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

I am trying to take the letters from the string 'Hello, World!' and convert it into values using a dictionary.

I've tried using strings and lists to see if this would work but can't figure it out.

```
d ={'H':1, 'e':2, 'l':3, 'o':4,',':5, ' ':6, 'W':7, 'r':8, 'd':9, '!':10}
mystr = 'Hello, World!'
mystr1 = d(mystr)
print(mystr1)
```

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable is the error I keep getting.

```
                   'Hello, World!'
```

My expected output is: '12334567483910'

If possible I would also like a way to convert the number back to the words 'Hello, World!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on each character of mystr. So using the `get` method, we can retrieve the value from the dictionary without causing an error if the character isn't there (and just leave it out), `for c in mystr` loops through each character, and the `str` function converts the integer from the dictionary to a string (if the values in the dictionary were strings you wouldn't need it, although then you could use `translate` as in Patrick's answer). Finally, `''.join` joins all the characters back together into a new string.

Instead of the `get` method, if you want it to throw an error if the character is not in the dictionary you can use `d[c]` instead of `d.get(c, '')`.

```
d ={'H':1, 'e':2, 'l':3, 'o':4,',':5, ' ':6, 'W':7, 'r':8, 'd':9, '!':10}
mystr = 'Hello, World'
encoded_string = ''.join(str(d.get(c, '')) for c in mystr)
print('Encoded String:', encoded_string)

r = dict((value, key) for key, value in d.items())
decoded_string = ''.join(r.get(int(c)) for c in encoded_string)
print('Decoded String:', decoded_string)
```

Result

```
Encoded String: 123345674839
Decoded String: Hello, World
```

Comment: How would I do the reverse to get the number back to 'Hello, World!'?

Comment: You could create a reverse dictionary. Call it `r`, then `r = dict((value, key) for key, value in d.items())`. Then use a similar method to access it. I've updated the answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're trying to do by converting your dictionary to a translation table and then using the [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method.

```
d = {'H':'1', 'e':'2', 'l':'3', 'o':'4',',':'5', ' ':'6', 'W':'7', 'r':'8', 'd':'9', '!':'10'}
tt = str.maketrans(d)
print("Hello, World!".translate(tt))
# 12334567483910
```

Note that we had to change the values of the dictionary from integers to strings, otherwise the [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) method treats them like Unicode ordinals.